# How to enable a button and disable other after a validation in c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, json, button, xamarin

Hi I have the following code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.Util;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Org.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using App1;
using App1.Resources;

namespace App1
{
[Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    EditText edtcpf;
    TextView txtnome;
    TextView txtorder;
    TextView txtsobrenome;
    TextView txtcpf;
    RestClient orderId { get; set; }
    RestClient consumer { get; set; }
    RestRequest cpf { get; set; }
    RestRequest requestorderId { get; set; }
    IRestResponse answerorder { get; set; }
    IRestResponse mensagemConsumer;
    Button btnConsumer;
    RadioButton cancelada;
    RadioButton aberta;
    RadioButton agendada;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        edtcpf = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtcpf);
        txtcpf = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtcpf);
        txtsobrenome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtresposta);
        txtnome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNome);
        txtorder = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtorder);
        btnConsumer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConsumer);
        cancelada = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.rdbtnCancelada);
        aberta = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.rdbtnAberta);
        agendada = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.rdbtnAgendada);
        btnConsumer.Click += BtnConsumer_Click;

    }

    private void BtnConsumer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // API Consumer CPF

            consumer = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers");
            cpf = new RestRequest("/" + edtcpf.Text, Method.GET);
            cpf.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            cpf.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 70197e6c-d81b-384c-bb32-d69e8c10b101");
            mensagemConsumer = consumer.Execute(cpf);
            Pessoa pessoa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pessoa>(mensagemConsumer.Content);
            txtnome.Text = "Nome: " + pessoa.firstName;
            txtsobrenome.Text = "Sobrenome: " + pessoa.lastName;

            // API Consumer Appliances
            orderId = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers/");
            requestorderId = new RestRequest("/" + edtcpf.Text + "/service-orders", Method.GET);
            requestorderId.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            requestorderId.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 70197e6c-d81b-384c-bb32-d69e8c10b101");
            answerorder = orderId.Execute(requestorderId);
            var requestToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(answerorder.Content);
            var parse = JObject.Parse(answerorder.Content);
            var QtdeItens = parse.Count;
            foreach (var order in requestToken.orders)
            {
                object vader = order.order.orderId;
                string darth = Convert.ToString(vader);
                string hora = order.order.orderOpeningDate;
                DateTime dia = Convert.ToDateTime(hora);
                txtorder.Text = "OrderId: " + darth + "ServiceProviderId: " + order.order.serviceProviderId + "Data de abertura: " + order.order.orderOpeningDate;

               if (order.order.orderStatusCode == "CANC")
                {
                    cancelada.Enabled = true;
                    agendada.Enabled = false;
                    aberta.Enabled = false;
                }

                else
                    if (order.order.orderStatusCode.Equals("ABRT"))
                {
                    cancelada.Enabled = false;
                    agendada.Enabled = false;
                    aberta.Enabled = true;

                }

                else
                    if (order.order.orderStatusCode.Contains("AGEN"))
                {
                    cancelada.Enabled = false;
                    agendada.Enabled = true;
                    aberta.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Which one is the correct?

```
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }




    }


}
```

}

I'm trying to enable a button depeding on the status the a Json answers has. It can be: **"Closed", "CANC", "ABRT" and "AGEN".** I created 3 radiobuttons and if the Json answer is CANC it show a button, if is ABRT it shows the second button and if it's AGEN the app shows the third button.

I tried it doing:

```
if (order.order.orderStatusCode == "CANC"){
       cancelada.Enabled = true;
       agendada.Enabled = false;
       aberta.Enabled = false;
 }
```

But it didn't work, so how can I do that?[image]

Comment: So you want to just _disable the radio buttons_ based on various conditions? And what's the issue here - they aren't getting disabled? What happens when you try clicking them?

Comment: Nothing homens it's just to the person knows how the request is: opened, closed or processing. Those buttons could be a message but I think that buttons have a better view

Comment: And yes depeding on the code I enable one button to show it and disable the others

Comment: If you have 3 radio buttons and you disable 2 in each scenario, then it doesn't make sense to have radio buttons. _'I enable one button to show it and disable the others'_ - I think you want to hide/show the buttons. Use `IsVisible` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 3 radio buttons and you disable 2 in each scenario, then it doesn't make sense to have radio buttons.

> I enable one button to show it and disable the others

I think you want to hide/show the buttons but are using the terms incorrectly. If that is the case then you should use `IsVisible` property instead of the `Enabled` property e.g

```
if (order.order.orderStatusCode == "CANC")
{
    cancelada.IsVisible = true;
    gendada.IsVisible = false;
    aberta.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Remember

- `IsVisible` is used to indicate whether to show the Visual Element or not
- `Enabled` is used to indicate whether the Visual Element accepts user input or not. For a button, this means the ability to tap it and for a text box, it means the ability to enter text in it.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Thank you I think that I expressed what I wanted in a wrong way ^^

Comment: @LucasMoreira You're welcome. If the answer helped solve your problem, you might want to mark it as accepted answer. Do note that you can only mark _one answer_ as the accepted answer (using the green check). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot. Find out with a debug what values are actually getting passed.

```
Debug.Log(order.order.orderStatusCode)
if (order.order.orderStatusCode == "CANC")
   {
    cancelada.Enabled = true;
    gendada.Enabled = false;
    aberta.Enabled = false;
   }
else if (order.order.orderStatusCode == "ABRT")
   {
    cancelada.Enabled = false;
    agendada.Enabled = false;
    aberta.Enabled = true;
    }
else if (order.order.orderStatusCode == "AGEN")
    {
     cancelada.Enabled = false;
     agendada.Enabled = true;
     aberta.Enabled = false;
    }
```